# .htaccess URL rewriting for CodeIgniter not working

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

I have the following `.htaccess` in `/home/domain/public_html/subfolder`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

But this doesn't work http://domain.com/subfolder/

> File does not exist: `/home/domian/public_html/public`

I apparently have my rewrite rules messed up. This entire CI application is in a subfolder of the web root.

```
/home/domain/public_html/subfolder
[sssss@ff subfolder]$ ls
application  license.txt  public  system  user_guide
```

and index.php is in public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your index.php should be in the same directory as application and system.

Once you moved it, try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Also on an unrelated note, I'd delete the user-guide directory since everything it contains is accessible at on the [CodeIgniter Site](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).